# Coldfusion Hash SHA-1 Doesnt look the same as the sample

Tags: hash, coldfusion, fingerprint

Im working on a script to hash a "fingerprint" for communicating with the secure Pay Direct Post API.

The issue I have is im trying to create a SHA-1 String that matches the sample code provided so that i can ensure things get posted accurately.

the example Sha-1 string appears encoded like

```
01a1edbb159aa01b99740508d79620251c2f871d
```

However my string when converted appears as

```
7871D5C9A366339DA848FC64CB32F6A9AD8FCADD
```

completely different...

my code for this is as follows..

```
<cfset variables.finger_print = "ABC0010|txnpassword|0|Test Reference|1.00|20110616221931">
<cfset variables.finger_print = hash(variables.finger_print,'SHA-1')>
<cfoutput>
#variables.finger_print#
</cfoutput>
```

Im using Coldfusion 8 to do this

it generates a 40 character hash, but i can see its generating completely different strings.

Hopefully someone out there has done this before and can point me in the right direction...

thanks in advance

** EDIT

The article for creating the Hash only contains the following information.

Example: Setting the fingerprint Fields joined with a | separator:

ABC0010|txnpassword|0|Test Reference|1.00|20110616221931

SHA1 the above string: 01a1edbb159aa01b99740508d79620251c2f871d

When generating the above example string using coldfusion hash it turns it into this

7871D5C9A366339DA848FC64CB32F6A9AD8FCADD

Comment: Confirm algorithm asked to use, as far as SHA algorithm generated key from coldfusion is correct. Make sure you are passing correct value as well.

Comment: Try online tool http://sha1-hash-online.waraxe.us/ for verification

Comment: Can you pls post the "sample code" too.

Comment: Ive run the string using the verification tool and it comes up correctly, however the coldfusion process is generating the final output incorrectly.


- thats all the code that i have been using to process it, is there any other variables i should be assigning to it ? Or is Coldfusion having problems processing it ?

Comment: I input your example string using the online tool that @PriteshPatel mentioned and it generates the same hash as the _ColdFusion_ example that you gave "7871D5C9A366339DA848FC64CB32F6A9AD8FCADD" - NOT the sample provided.  So ColdFusion and the online tool match. I also entered your string at http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm which generates several different hashes. None of them matched your sample.  Are you sure the generated sample hash is using SHA-1?

Comment: @user125264 - Can you post the "sample code" from the API? I think that is what Adam was asking for earlier ..

Comment: I just posted an edit on the code, it doesnt actually contain any code. the link to the actual document im referring to is here - http://www.camtech.com.au/docs/Direct_Post_Integration_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> `01a1edbb159aa01b99740508d79620251c2f871d`

Sorry, but I do not see how the sample string could possibly produce that result given that php, CF and java all say otherwise. I suspect an error in the documentation. The one thing that stands out is the use of "txnpassword" instead of a sample value, like with the other fields. Perhaps they used a different value to produce the string and forgot to plug it into the actual example?

**Update:**

Example 5.2.1.12, on page 27, makes more sense. Ignoring case, the results from ColdFusion match exactly. I noticed the description also mentions something about a `summarycode` value, which is absent from the example in section 3.3.6. So that tends to support the theory of documentation error with the earlier example.

**Code:**

```
 <cfset input = "ABC0010|mytxnpasswd|MyReference|1000|201105231545|1">
 <cfoutput>#hash(input, "sha-1")#</cfoutput>
```

**Result:**

```
 3F97240C9607E86F87C405AF340608828D331E10
```